# Is there an SQL Server equivalent function to Progress 4GL INTERVAL function ?

Tags: sql-server, progress-4gl

I am aware that Progress 4GL version 10 onwards is equipped with an very clever integrated function called 'INTERVAL' which returns the time interval between two DATE, DATETIME, or DATETIME-TZ values. 
If you use the following syntax,

```
> DISPLAY INTERVAL(05/06/2014, 05/05/2015, "years").
```

would give you zero as it is one day short for it to be counted as one year.

But in SQL, the closet function can be used in relation to this would be DATEDIFF and you would not be able to get the same result. In SQL Server the following query,

> `PRINT DATEDIFF(YEAR, '05/06/2014', '05/05/2015');`

would still print one instead of zero ignoring the bit that it is still one day short to be counted as a year. 
Therefore my question is would there be an integrated function in SQL which could be used to achieve the same result like Progress 4GL ?

Comment: I don't know of any function like that in SQL but what you can do to get the same result is to use `DATEDIFF(DAY, '05/06/2014', '05/05/2015')` then divide that by 365. If the difference is less than 365 days then the integer division will return 0. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be helpful but it looks like my ssms does not recognize the functions.

Comment: Is that the only difference between `INTERVAL` and `DATEDIFF` that yuo need to resolve or does it need to be functionally identical? Are you converting postgres to SQL Server?

Comment: Yes i was looking for something functionally identical ? I am not converting Progress to SQL and it wouldn't be possible either i was trying to find similar function in SQL as i knew there is one exists in Progress 4GL.

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF returns the number of specified boundaries crossed between the 2 dates.  This works well for days, but is less useful for months and years,

Below is one method to calculate the differences in years in T-SQL, as in a common age calculation.  It's not very robust but gets the job done.  The core issue is that SQL Server doesn't have an interval data type.

```
--using YYYY-MM-DD date format literal to avoid ambiguity
DECLARE @date1 date = '2014-05-06', @date2 date = '2015-05-05';

--years between 2 dates
SELECT (CAST(CONVERT(char(8), @date2, 112) AS int) - CAST(CONVERT(char(8), @date1, 112) AS int)) / 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, for this sort of problem you can calculate a figure at a finer granularity and then resolve it to a coarser one. In this case, you can figure out the number of days between the two dates and then divide by 365 and floor the result.

```
DECLARE @date1 date = '2014-05-06', @date2 date = '2015-05-05';

SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, @date1, @date2)/365.0)
```

Of course, leap years present a bit of a challenge. But there's the general idea.